PHP function not consuming JSON output body variable when using WordPress REST API POST
I’m attempting to call a PHP function via the WordPress RestAPI and for the life of me cannot figure out how to pass a JSON variable to the following function:
    function update_user_status_to_pending_from_api (WP_REST_Request $ID){
    $userID = $ID->get_json_params();
    wp_set_object_terms( $userID, array( 'pending' ), 'user_status', false );
    clean_object_term_cache( $userID, 'user_status' );
    return $ID;
    return $userID;
    }

I’d like to pass the ID variable via the JSON body at the time of the rest API request and the function fires when I call it via my make.com RestAPI module and I have ID in the JSON body, but the script does not consume the value. Even if I append ?ID=3 to the URL the script ignores the value.
I enabled PHP debugging both in WP and PHP which displays nothing when the function is called. When I use curl, I receive a response of 200, but I receive no $ID or $userID output as stated in the function.

After some exhaustive research I found that you must specify the JSON value you want the variable to consume
function update_user_status_to_pending_from_api (\WP_REST_Request $request){
        $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
        $userID = $parameters["id"];
        wp_set_object_terms( $userID, array( 'pending' ), 'user_status', false );
   clean_object_term_cache( $userID, 'user_status' );
  }

I can call this successfully via a curl command and passing {"id":value} in the string
